# I'm having trouble with react

Tags: reactjs

This is my first post on github . I only speak very little English , So i so sorry . run ALERT . i want that thing . Please help me

this is my App page

```
import React from 'react';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import Counter from './Counter';
import {createStore} from 'redux';

const initialState = {
    count : 0
};

function reducer( state = initialState, action){

    if(action.type === "ALERT" ){
        alert("ahihi");
    }

    return state
}


const store = createStore(reducer);

const App = () => (
    <Provider store ={store}>
        <Counter />
    </Provider>

);

export default App;
```

this is my Counter page

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from "react-redux"
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';

export const ahihi = () => ({
  type: "ALERT"
});


const Counter = ({ab}) => {

        return (
                <div>
                        <button onClick={ALERT} ></button>
                </div>
        );
}
const a = (dispatch) =>({
    a : bindActionCreators(ahihi, dispatch)
}
export default connect(a)(Counter)
```

run ALERT . i want that thing . Please help me

Comment: What happens currently when you run your code? Do you get any errors?

Comment: You defined your action as `ahihi` (with `type: "ALERT"`), but then reference it as `ALERT`. You need to replace that second `ALERT` in the `onClick` with `ahihi`.

Comment: @HenryWoody Please go through the code again, What you have stated is incorrect and would only serve to confuse OP.

Comment: @ManavM Okay, looking at UjinT34's answer it seems that `ALERT` should actually be `a` and `ab` should actually be `a` as well. I doubt my comment would be that confusing as it would at least point OP in the direction of the solution—using incorrect variable names

Comment: While I agree that `ALERT` is wrong, `ahihi` will not achieve anything there. What OP needs to do is to access the function that `connect` has injected into the component which the answer below illustrates.

Comment: Regardless..The answer below should solve any confusions so it's all good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`connect` takes `mapStateToProps` as first argument. If you don't need this you can just

```
export default connect(null, a)(Counter)
```

`Counter` needs to get `a` defined in your `mapDispatchToProps` and use it as `onClick` event handler:

```
const Counter = ({a}) => {

        return (
                <div>
                        <button onClick={a} ></button>
                </div>
        );
}
```

Comment: tks a lot  you are my hero